# iOS: PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks

Tags: ios, xcode

Why do I get this iOS building error in Xcode? All I did I removed a Pod dependency.

```
PhaseScriptExecution [CP]\ Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/kukodajanos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PFB-bafucuhiagkkscdsptpvoqgmfnqe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PFB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BVR\ -\ ACM\ Air\ Charter.build/Script-C4371EFF22C5F93C00E66DEA.sh (in target 'BVR - ACM Air Charter' from project 'PFB')
    cd /Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/IFS/PFB
    /bin/sh -c /Users/kukodajanos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PFB-bafucuhiagkkscdsptpvoqgmfnqe/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PFB.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/BVR\\\ -\\\ ACM\\\ Air\\\ Charter.build/Script-C4371EFF22C5F93C00E66DEA.sh
```

and:

```
mkdir -p /Users/kukodajanos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/PFB-bafucuhiagkkscdsptpvoqgmfnqe/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PFB BVR.app/Frameworks
/Users/kukodajanos/Workspace/IFS/PFB/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-BVR - ACM Air Charter/Pods-BVR - ACM Air Charter-frameworks.sh: line 42: source: unbound variable
```

and the `.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e
set -u
set -o pipefail

function on_error {
  echo "$(realpath -mq "${0}"):$1: error: Unexpected failure"
}
trap 'on_error $LINENO' ERR

if [ -z ${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH+x} ]; then
  # If FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH is not set, then there's nowhere for us to copy
  # frameworks to, so exit 0 (signalling the script phase was successful).
  exit 0
fi

echo "mkdir -p ${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"
mkdir -p "${CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}"

COCOAPODS_PARALLEL_CODE_SIGN="${COCOAPODS_PARALLEL_CODE_SIGN:-false}"
SWIFT_STDLIB_PATH="${DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR}/usr/lib/swift/${PLATFORM_NAME}"
BCSYMBOLMAP_DIR="BCSymbolMaps"


# This protects against multiple targets copying the same framework dependency at the same time. The solution
# was originally proposed here: https://lists.samba.org/archive/rsync/2008-February/020158.html
RSYNC_PROTECT_TMP_FILES=(--filter "P .*.??????")

# Copies and strips a vendored framework
install_framework()
{
  if [ -r "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/$1" ]; then
    local source="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/$1"
  elif [ -r "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/$(basename "$1")" ]; then
    local source="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/$(basename "$1")"
  elif [ -r "$1" ]; then
    local source="$1"
  fi
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Having a very similar issue

Comment: I have two Mac, before I used old for development, no turned to the new one, and now issue happend anymore.